# How do i write css for “item-native” class?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

i have tried to write css for the “item-native” class in ion-item but it was not applied how can i write custom css for the “item-native” class

[image]

Comment: Try to add like this `.ion-untouched .item-native{.. style here ....}`

Comment: You are trying to style `shadow-root`, I am not sure if that is possible without involvement of js. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```css
ion-item::part(native) {
 /* Custom CSS here */
}
```

Comment: This works well. The ::part pseudo-element selector is a good fit to style content within the shadow-root of the ion-item custom element - better than ::ng-deep, >>> or /deep/. More info can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part

Comment: .cardItems ion-item::part(native) {
    border-style: none !important;
}

I want to use it like this but it is not working

Comment: @Carljul Maybe this link will help:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts

It shows you how to style ionic shadow parts.

Answer (score 0):

If your style does not working that means either your other styles are overwriting your custom css or you have written your styles at wrong place.

Just try writing first at the root css, just for the testing whether it works or not.

```css
.item-native {
  // Add your custom css here, write important at the end like this
   color: red !important;
}
```